# Selenium chromedriver detected and blocked by website

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape a website using Selenium chromedriver on java. I can't load the page because it's detecting me as a bot. The google Chrome Browser and chromedriver versions are correct. I tried different ways but I'm not able to load the page.
Here is my code:

```
//I have a button that initializes this class

public class Bet365 {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public String url = "https://www.bet365.com";
    static {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();         
        
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");  
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-automation");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1280,800");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36");                     
            
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);            
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                
    }        
    
    
    public void bet365() throws InterruptedException{        
        startBet365();
        driver.quit();            
    };

    
    public void startBet365(){            
        driver.get(url);                 
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: If web crawlers are blocked from the web site the only thing you can do is ask webmaster to allow selenium.

Comment: It's possible to scrap the website because I know programs capable of doing it

Comment: Have you tried to [use proxies with Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/)?

Comment: I tried but, as you can see in my profile, I have another question about proxies. If you know about proxies, I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same but its loading . I am having code with python you can easily do it with you language.
Her you can try with :-

```
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    # options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    # options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])
    options.add_argument("log-level=3")
```

and thenyou can add :-

```
options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36')
```

After useragent add thease :

```
    driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => false})")

    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source":
        "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
        "delete newProto.webdriver;"
        "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
})
driver.set_window_size(1400, 920)
```

you can also try with chromium binary files.It will help you too.